# Trouble to justify a form

Tags: html, css

I'm asking if I'm noob or stupid but I need to shrink/center, and align space-around my form but I can't and I don't know why. I tried to flex-shrink but it shrinked completely and when I used too resize the width by 50% for example, and Justify-content, nothing happend ... I'm sorry to ask question in this case but could someone help me please?

Here is my HTML:

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav{
    background-color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
}

li:first-child{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 45%;
    height: 50px;
    color: rgb(233, 230, 230);
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;  
}

ul li{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.803);
    color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
    border: 0.1px solid rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
}

.carousel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

h2{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    vertical-align: end;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

#fellowsTitle{
    justify-content: center;
}

#subtitle{
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#fellows{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow : row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

hr{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#contactUs{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

form{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: space-around;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Find the precious!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>FindThePrecious.com</li>
              <li>Fellows</li>
              <li>Contact us</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
          <div class="carousel"></div>
      </section>
      <section>
          <h2 id="fellowsTitle">Fellows wanted dead &nbsp; <a id="subtitle">(or alive if you want to eat them later)</a></h2>
      </section>
      <section id="fellows">
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>         
      </section>
      <hr>
      <h2 id="contactUs">Contact us</h2>
      <form>
          <input type="email" placeholder="@">
          <input type="text" placeholder="&#8962;">
          <input type="text" placeholder="I have seen one of them">
          <textarea placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want to achieve, then you can just add `margin` attribute to your form:

```
form {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 20px; /* HERE you can also use padding instead */
}
```

a working snippet:

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav{
    background-color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
}

li:first-child{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 45%;
    height: 50px;
    color: rgb(233, 230, 230);
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;  
}

ul li{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.803);
    color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
    border: 0.1px solid rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
}

.carousel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

h2{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    vertical-align: end;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(69, 67, 67, 0.756);
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

#fellowsTitle{
    justify-content: center;
}

#subtitle{
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#fellows{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow : row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

hr{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#contactUs{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-left: 20px;
    
}

form{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Find the precious!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>FindThePrecious.com</li>
              <li>Fellows</li>
              <li>Contact us</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <section>
          <div class="carousel"></div>
      </section>
      <section>
          <h2 id="fellowsTitle">Fellows wanted dead &nbsp; <a id="subtitle">(or alive if you want to eat them later)</a></h2>
      </section>
      <section id="fellows">
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>
          <article><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="blabla"/></article>         
      </section>
      <hr>
      <h2 id="contactUs">Contact us</h2>
      <form>
          <input type="email" placeholder="@">
          <input type="text" placeholder="&#8962;">
          <input type="text" placeholder="I have seen one of them">
          <textarea placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to center without a margin, just using flexbox. Normaly I could align-items: space-around (doesn't work too)... I don't know why

Comment: Ah, Ok you should have said so in the question! ok let me check

Comment: @JeanReno, what is the issue with using margin/padding? also I don't see how to have like this without a hacky work around.